# Обменять элементы двух массивов на месте так, чтобы их новый контент также был обращен вспять

Tags: python, list

Это тестовая функция

```
exchange_with(a, b)
Test.assert_equals(a, ["c", "b", "a"])
Test.assert_equals(b,['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Дан вот такой пример:

```
# before

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

other_list = [1, 2, 3]

exchange_with(my_list, other_list)

# after

my_list == [3, 2, 1]

other_list == ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Задача написать функцию! Вот моё решение но тест на тестируемой системе не прохожу

```
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]

b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def exchange_with(a, b):
    a, b = b[::-1], a[::-1]
    return f"{a},\n {b}"

print(exchange_with(a, b))
```

Вот что выдаёт print()

```
['c', 'b', 'a']

['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Подскажите где моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что снаружи функции `exchange_with` массивы `a` и `b` не изменились. Вам внутри функции надо менять содержимое существующих массивов `a` и `b`, а не присваивать этим переменным (параметрам) ссылки на новые массивы.

```
def exchange_with(a, b):
    tempA = a.copy()
    tempB = b.copy()
    a.clear()
    b.clear()
    # insert items from tempB into a in reverse order
    # insert items from tempA into b in reverse order
```

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что снаружи функции exchange_with массивы a и b не изменились... пишите Вы , но я пробывал вариант меняя массивы местами в глобальной области , а потом они передавались как параметры и внутри функции их тоже менял , но ни чего не получается.Тестовая система не пропускает ответ.https://www.codewars.com/kata/5353212e5ee40d4694001114/train/python вот сайт откуда я решаю задачи и даю ссылку на эту "ката"

Comment: `def exchange_with(a, b):
    tempA = a.copy()
    tempB = b.copy()
    a.clear()
    b.clear()
    for elem in tempB[::-1]:
        a.append(elem)
    for elem in tempA[::-1]:
        b.append(elem)
    # insert items from tempB into a in reverse order
    # insert items from tempA into b in reverse order
    return f"{a},\n {b}"` , а почему нельзя развернуть массивы прямо в return, С глубокой признательностью и уважением, спасибо!Тестовая система приняла решение.

Comment: @андреймарченков Насколько я понимаю, `return` вообще не нужен. Тест хочет, чтобы вы *изменили содержимое уже созданных массивов*, ссылки на которые существуют снаружи Вашей функции и передаются туда как параметры.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, убрал return f"{a},\n {b}" и тестовая система опять приняла решение.А вот насчёт return , я начинающий и моя логика такая раз это функция то укажи явно return и + к нему что-то , а то получу без него None

Comment: После правильного решения данной "ката", я был допущен на страничку где выложены все решения участников сайта вот есть какие красивые и простые решения:`def exchange_with(a, b):
    a[:], b[:] = b[::-1], a[::-1]`        вот ещё `def exchange_with(a, b):
    c = a.copy()
    a.clear()
    while b:
        a.append(b.pop())
    while c:
        b.append(c.pop())`   и вот ещё `def exchange_with(a, b):

    a.reverse()
    b.reverse()

    temp = []
    temp.extend(a)
    
    a.clear()
    a.extend(b)
    
    b.clear()
    b.extend(temp)
    return`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def exchange_with(a, b):
    a, b = b, a
    a.reverse()
    b.reverse()
    return a, b

c = exchange_with(a, b)

for i in c:
    print(i)
```

Но неплохо бы конечный ответ посмотреть. Что тест вернуть должен. Если Вам нужно развернуть именно срезом, то тогда в return, уберите запятую и после переноса уберите отступ.

Comment: Test Results: Passed: 0 Failed: 2 Exit Code: 1
['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1'] should equal ['c', 'b', 'a']
['c', 'b', 'a'] should equal ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']Вот что выдала тестирующая система

Comment: @андреймарченков Попробуйте перечитать мой ответ, чтобы понять, почему это происходит.

Comment: @Igor Вот я пытаюсь создать новые массивы внутри функции используя значения из глобальных массивов и разворачиваю созданные массивы делаю проверку и опять ошибка. Извини но понять наверное мне не дано перебирал много вариантов def exchange_with(a, b):
    a1 = []
    b1 = []
    for number in b:
        a1.append(number)
    for number in a:
        b1.append(number)
    return f"{a1[::-1]},\n {b1[::-1]}"